# No original event on touchstart

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, google-chrome, touchstart

So i'm using JQuery (1.11.3) and I've been stuck on something for which I can't find anything on the web.

Basically, I'm binding a handler to a 'touchstart' event and want to retrieve the position of the touch event. (note: I also tried with `$('#id').on('touchstart'...` )

```
$(document).bind('touchstart','#main-button', function( e ){
    alert(Object.keys(e).join('\n'));
    alert(Object.keys(e.originalEvent).join('\n'));
    // awesome code here
})
```

This is what I get from the first alert:

[image: screenshot android 1]
[image: screenshot android 2]

The problem is that the originalEvent (which is supposed to have the information I'm looking for) only has the property **isTrusted**.

[image: screenshot android 3]

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong ? I'm using Chrome for Android by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `originalEvent` does have other properties (see [MDN reference for touchstart event property list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchstart)). `Object.keys` is just not returning them. This is because either the properties are not enumerable or they are defined somewhere in the prototype chain.

Instead you can use a [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop to get any enumerable properties on the object and those in the prototype chain.

```
$(document).bind('touchstart','#main-button', function( e ){
    alert(Object.keys(e).join('\n'));
    var keys = "";
    for(key in e.originalEvent){
       keys+=key+"\n";
    }
    alert(keys);
    // awesome code here
})
```

Comment: Thank you ! :)
I was putting too much faith in my alerts haha. I didn't know `Objects.keys()` could omit some properties. Damn I miss the `console.log()` on my phone.

Comment: Can't you use **chrome://inspect** to see your app then? [link to remote-debugging on developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging)